# Media Element doesn't work after installing Mango developer tools

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm downloading a voice file from the internet and save it in isolated storage. The I pass this file to a media element on the page and then I call the Play() method. The app was working fine until I installed Mango developer tools. Since then the media element doesn't play the file.

```
  private void DownloadCompleted(System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream _Result)
    {
        if (_Result.CanRead && (bool)chkSpeak.IsChecked)
        {
            mediaElement1.SetSource(_Result);
            mediaElement1.Play();
        }
    }


<MediaElement Height="111" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="mediaElement1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"  Volume="1" AutoPlay="True" IsHitTestVisible="True" />
```

Do I need to make any changes in my code?

Comment: I assume you mean it doesn't work in the Mango emulator. What about a pre-mango device? Are you targetting 7.0 or 7.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Release Notes](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26648) (I assume you mean `beta 2`), these two are known issues:

> When Windows Phone Emulator is running
>   on Windows Vista, some audio problems
>   may occur. This issue is caused by
>   lost audio packets when playing audio
>   such as media files or alarms.
>
> Setting the source of a MediaElement
>   object fails every other time.

Might be related. (Are you using Vista/does SetSource work intermittently?)